# How to show on Leaflet: WMS on top of OpenMapTiles (vector PBF)?

Tags: leaflet, wms, google-maps-api, openmaptiles

I made a simple Leaflet page with the following content:

Overlays:

1. a geojson polygon file
2. WMS polygon layer from Geoserver of my own (tiled=true)

Baselayers:

1. All 4 Google Maps: road, terrain, satellite, hybrid (from internet); with [Google Mutant](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant) Leaflet plugin
2. OpenStreetMaps (from internet)
3. OpenMapTiles (of my own from my intranet)
4. a blank baselayer

Everything is smooth but one thing: every time i turn on my OpenMapTiles (OMT), my WMS dissapear from map; and the WMS will be shown normally again with baselayer other than OMT.

I tried to remove Google baselayers (as well as script reference to Google Maps API accordingly) from the page, hence only OMT, OSM and blank baselayer remain. But the WMS won't show with OMT baselayer.

Any clue why this is happening and how to fix this?

The stack includes:

- Leaflet 1.3.3
- GeoServer 2.7.0 (for the polygon WMS)
- Tomcat 8.5.32 on port 8080
- OpenMapTiles on IIS behind an F5 reverse proxy

Comment: WMS gives an image even if source is vector

Comment: @nmtoken forgive me i don't understand your comment. But at least i do understand that a GeoServer WMS endpoint will serve PNG images (with a vector datasource behind the WMS). In my case there's definitely something wrong as the WMS won't show if the OMT baselayer is on. Otherwise the WMS shows normally. Any clue?

Comment: Sorry thought it might be a transparency issue, but re-reading, I see that probably isn't the case, only other thought is they have the same name somehow